# To run .msi files in C# Project?

Tags: c#

I have a source code in C# language..In setup guide they asked to
"Run SampleWebService_Setup.msi and sample2Service.Setup.msi on a machine" .
But while I trying to file out that file I could find only SampleWebService_Setup.vdproj and
sample2Service.Setup.vdproj
How To resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

try with this code

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/i yourMSI.msi";
p.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to open this with Visual Studio? Sounds like the two projects might be application installer projects.

If so, you can open the projects in VS and build them. You should then find an MSI installation file in either the `/bin` folder of the project.